# WPF - How to Center a label's Content inside the label

Tags: c#, wpf

I created some labels in a `for` loop on the behind code.
At the beginning it looks like that:

```
private void SlotLabelCreation(string name)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Name = name;
    label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    label.Content = "[Free Slot]";
    label.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
    label.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
    label.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
    label.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    MainGrid.Children.Add(label);

    //the margin has been inserted later in other code.
}
```

everything was fine but when I inserted to the label other content which not contains the same amount of letters it looks like that:

*sorry about the links.. it's because I can't upload images*

http://s27.postimg.org/6halp6p37/pic2.png

I wanted to make all slots the same size so I added a `MinWidth` property to the labels.
The new result was:

http://s27.postimg.org/6z5r51eo3/pic3.png

now it looks better but I am wondering how could I center the content which inside the label.
Unfortunately I didn't find any solution to solve this problem.

p.s, `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` don't solve the problem.

Thanks a lot, Alon P.

Comment: are you looking for the `HorizontalContentAlignment`/`VerticalContentAlignment` properties?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in code behind instead of XAML?

Comment: Yes because I am creating 126 Labels

Comment: @AlonP that does not mean that you can't do it in XAML.

Comment: @kennyzx Of course it possible, but then I couldn't do it with a 'for' loop.. Or maybe there is an option to do a loop in Xaml which I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment properties

Comment: Wow, it works!  
I didn't know that there is a HorizontalContentAlignment / VerticalContentAlignment properties.. I have searched for a solution for 3 hours!